# Recursively Delete Folders and All Contained Files

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete nested folders I generate after zipping/downloading the contents, but I'm running into an issue where I end up with an empty folder that can't be deleted. I found this answer in a similar question, and a bunch of versions of it, but for some reason the last folder thinks it is not empty despite having no contents.

```
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
  $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
  if (is_array($structure)) {
    foreach($structure as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
        elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
    }
  }
  rmdir($dir);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Do you have physical access to machine / shell to confirm that this directory is empty.
What is your environment? LAMP? WAMP? Other? What is the type of filesystem you are creating those files?

Comment: above rmdir try the following code for debug purposes and edit the resulting code & its output into your question please: https://bpaste.net/show/642514db022f

Comment: I am using WAMP running php 7.0.4 - it's possible that the recursion is out-pacing the files being deleted, but when I physically look at the directory that's trying to be deleted there's nothing in it - I'm deleting a bunch of versions of plain HTML assets (banners), and it's weird that only one of them gets missed when they all have the same structure.

Comment: Xatenev, as strange as it is, pasting the code on top actually fixed the problem...I know it wasn't supposed to, I'm wondering if having to fire that function just delayed it long enough to realize my last directory wasn't empty

Comment: I was able to simplify it to... $openCheck = opendir($dir);
closedir($openCheck); I'm assuming because it pauses to open/close the directory it verifies that it is empty before deleting, which did the trick!

Comment: Note you can create a zip file without writing the individual content files to disk. Just use `ZipArchive::addFromString` and then there's nothing to clean up when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It was trying to delete too many folders too quickly - having the system open/close the folder was enough for it to verify there was nothing inside and deleted everything as intended.

```
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
  $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
  if (is_array($structure)) {
    foreach($structure as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
        elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
    }
  }
  //Opening and closing the directory forces system to recognize it is empty
  $openCheck = opendir($dir);
  closedir($openCheck);
  //Remove directory after done removing all children
  rmdir($dir);
}
```

Thank you Xatenev for putting me on the right track! I feel like this might be a little janky - if anyone has a better idea please let me know!

Comment: Why are you creating everything on your local filesystem just to zip it and delete it when you can make the zip programmatically  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Remove directory recursively.
 *
 * @param string $path Path
 * @return bool True on success or false on failure.
 */
function rrmdir($path) {
    $files = glob($path . '/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        is_dir($file) ? rrmdir($file) : unlink($file);
    }
    return rmdir($path);
}
```